# Neo4j: execute set of statements based on condition

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to execute certain statements, including `MERGE`, collect operations, etc., based on a condition.

Roughly like this :

```
if(condition1)
  statement1. 
  statement2
else if(condition2)
 statement3
 statement4
```

and so on. How to achieve this in Neo4j?

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible with only Cypher statements.

But you can install [APOC Procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures) and use `apoc.when` or `apoc.do.when` procedures.

The documentation says about `apoc.when`:

> **apoc.when(condition, ifQuery, elseQuery:'', params:{}) yield value** -
>   based on the conditional, executes read-only ifQuery or elseQuery with
>   the given parameters

and about `apoc.do.when`:

> **apoc.do.when(condition, ifQuery, elseQuery:'', params:{}) yield value**
>   - based on the conditional, executes writing ifQuery or elseQuery with the given parameters

That is: `apoc.when` should be used to execute read-only queries while `apoc.do.when` should be used to execute write queries.

Comment: HI thanks a lot for the help :) It worked in the above case. By any chance, i can make it work in a case, where if any of the statements are a return statement? like 
 if(match == null)
     return
 continue with other statements